# UI display bug while viewing edit history

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

While looking at the edit history of [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/61591/revisions), there is a display bug with revision headers. The headers overflow outside the bounds of the revision block.

[image: overflowed headers]

The bug appears to be caused by a lengthy code-block within the initial revision history. Looking at the page source and CSS, the initial revision is missing a set `width` (which is set to `460px` in the side-by-side view, thus not causing any overflow)

[image: initial revision history]

Collapsing the initial revision history results in the overflowed headers to return to a normal state

[image: normalized headers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as reported https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361474/235711 and https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10631/14975.

I think this predates me breaking things, and was a manifestation of the same bug reported on Code Review.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! :)